# Harmonic Series in fraction form

Tags: python, math

Does anyone know how to code the [Harmonic Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) in python?

```
H(n) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ... + 1/n
```

Note: We're not allowed to import from predefined modules. The output must be the numerator and the denominator of the answer in fraction form (lowest terms).

Oh, I'm sorry. I'm just a beginner. I'm so sorry. so here's my code for this harmonic series.

```
n = input("Enter n:")  

def harmonic(n):  
    a=1  
    b=1  
    for d in range(2, n+1):  
            a = a*d+b  
            b = b*d  
            return (a,b)  
            x == max(a,b)%min(a, b)  
            if x == 0:  
                y=min(a,b)  
                return y  
            else:  
                y=min(a,b)/x  
                return y  
            a=a/y  
            b=b/y  
            return (a,b)  
print harmonic(n)
```

what's wrong? Whatever I input,  the output is always (3,2).. what's wrong ?? :( Help please.. thanks :)

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't take kindly to solving your problems for you. That's not the purpose. Instead if you have specific questions about how something works, tell us your thought process and what you have researched up to this point and you will get some non-sarcastic answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without modules, what you'll have to do is implement fraction addition yourself. Besides, to get the result in lowest terms, you'll need to implement/get a `gcd` function.

When you do `a/b + c/d`, the result (without normalization) is `(ad+bc)/bd`. In the harmonic series, notice one of the numerators (`c` in this case) is 1 every time, so the result would be `(ad+b)/bd`.

So, call `a` the current numerator, `b` the current denominator, and `d` the next denominator in the series. The pseudocode would be something like the following. `n` is the input integer.

1. `a` ← 1  { Will start from `1/1` }
2. `b` ← 1
3. For all `d` in [2..`n`] { From `1/2` to `1/n`, do the following }

   1. `a` ← `a*d + b`
   2. `b` ← `b*d`
   3. `x` ← `gcd(a,b)` { Normalization begins here }
   4. `a` ← `a/x`
   5. `b` ← `b/x`
4. Output (`a`, `b`)

Comment: Here's my code.. :)
n = input("Enter n:")  

def harmonic(n):  
    a=1  
    b=1  
    for d in range(2, n+1):  
        a = a*d+b  
        b = b*d  
        return (a,b)  
        x == max(a,b)%min(a, b)  
        if x == 0:  
            y=min(a,b)  
            return y  
        else:  
            y=min(a,b)/x  
            return y  
        a=a/y  
        b=b/y  
        return (a,b)  
print harmonic(n)